# ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'beta', 4), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1)

Tags: python, mysql, macos, python-2.7, mysql-python

I've installed MySQL-python on mac with following procedure :

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
brew install mysql
pip install MySQL-python
```

Then test it :

```
python -c "import MySQLdb"
```

When I test it, it gave me following error on my mac terminal :

> ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'beta', 4), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1)

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 8):

I had this error when I was running a Python program `airflow`:

**Issue**

```
$airflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/idx/.virtualenvs/airflow/bin/airflow", line 16, in <module>
    from airflow import configuration
  File "/home/idx/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from airflow import settings
  File "/home/idx/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 150, in <module>
configure_orm()
  File "/home/idx/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 136, in configure_orm
engine = create_engine(SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN, **engine_args)
  File "/home/idx/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 419, in create_engine
return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/idx/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 80, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/home/idx/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 102, in dbapi
    return __import__('MySQLdb')
  File "/home/idx/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
(version_info, _mysql.version_info))
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 4, 1, 'final', 0)
```

**Background**

The MySQLdb that I was using was in: `/home/will/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/`. A `cat release.py` in that directory showed the `1.2.5 final 1`.

```
__author__ = "Andy Dustman <farcepest@gmail.com>"
version_info = (1,2,5,'final',1)
__version__ = "1.2.5"
```

**Fix**

To make the versions match, I ran the below and that fixed it for me:

```
# for some reason, even though I had mysqlclient==1.4.1 from pip freeze, I had to uninstall it first, then reinstall
pip uninstall mysqlclient
pip install mysqlclient==1.4.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Under the path:

> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

On my mac I can see ***MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7.egg-info*** and ***MySQLdb***
Just remove the file MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7.egg-info/ can fix the problem:

> sudo rm -rf MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7.egg-info/

Answer (score 1):

This is a compatiability issue. What i did was put my mysql python to 1.2.4b.4.

If you have mysqldb installed uninstall with

**pip uninstall MySQL-python**

then install with same version:

**pip install mysql-python==1.2.4b4**

This is the beta hence the b

This works for me. I tested by going into python interactive with python

then import MySQLdb and it worked. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Do

> ```
>  pip uninstall mysqlclient
> ```

then do

> ```
> pip install mysqlclient==1.3.14
> ```

as 1.4.1 version having some issues

Answer (score 0):

You can re-install your `MySQLdb-python` and install this version: [MySQLdb-python-1.2.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5)

```
    pip uninstall MySQL_python
    pip install -Iv https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip#md5=654f75b302db6ed8dc5a898c625e030c
```

Comment: I did as you asked and I was able to install MySQLdb-python. The problem is I need to import MySQLdb module to my python code which runs on My google app engine. but somehow I'm still getting the error " No module named MySQLdb."

Comment: you could check this [lib_in_python:pip](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring)

Comment: i checked, not helping :(

Comment: What if I want to use a newer mysql-python? `but _mysql is version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1)`, what is the corresponding package for `_mysql`? Is is possible to update / upgrade that `_mysql`?