# Unable to import MySQLdb on Ubuntu 20

Tags: python, ubuntu, mysql-python

I have a legacy python 2.7 app which imports MySQLdb. I'm trying to move my app from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20 in preparation for upgrade to python 3. This import fails as follows:

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Jul  1 2022, 12:27:04)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ml/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried uninstall/reinstall of libmysqlclient-dev.

After including the bionic repositories and installing libmysqlclient20 (as suggested) I was seeing:

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Jul  1 2022, 12:27:04)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ml/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    (version_info, _mysql.version_info))
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 4, 6, 'final', 0)
```

... so I followed the suggestion found here:
[ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'beta', 4), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881402/importerror-this-is-mysqldb-version-1-2-4-beta-4-but-mysql-is-version)

```
pip uninstall mysqlclient
pip install mysqlclient==1.3.14
```

... problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/471788) that missing the same library, it looks like the library you needed isn't available in Ubuntu 20's default APT repositories.

However, in Ubuntu 20, you can try [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/623845) from the question. Which adds some repositories from Ubuntu 18.

The following commands (from *the answer* above but uses bionic repository) might do the trick.

```bash
# Adds the Bionic repo.
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list > /dev/null <<EOF
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
EOF

# Update APT lists and install the library.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libmysqlclient20
```